# How to select the first item in a navigation drawer and open a fragment on application start

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created `MainActivity` with `NavigationView`. When `Activity` is opened I want to automatically select the first item in the navigation drawer and open `Fragment` under that item. I've searched a lot but didn't find any proper solutions.

What is the proper way to do this ?

`Main Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Config {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIcons));

    if (null != getSupportActionBar())
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_blogger_white);

    //Start PostListFragmentWebView
    /*PostListFragmentWebView postListFragmentWebView = new PostListFragmentWebView();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, postListFragmentWebView)
            .commit();*/

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not set it to checked state.
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was clicked and perform the appropriate action.
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.posts:
                    PostListFragmentWebView postListFragment = new PostListFragmentWebView();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame, postListFragment)
                            .commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.pages:
                    PageListFragmentWebView pagetListFragment = new PageListFragmentWebView();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame, pagetListFragment)
                            .commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.blog:
                    BlogInfoFragmentWebView blogInfoFragment = new BlogInfoFragmentWebView();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame, blogInfoFragment)
                            .commit();
                    return true;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }

        }
    });

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we don't want anything to happen so we leave this blank.
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank.

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    drawerLayout.getChildAt(0).setSelected(true);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried to call navigationView.getMenu().findItem(menuItemId).setChecked(true)

Comment: This just marks the item as selected I already did this in xml..

Comment: getMenu from navigationView and then call [performIdentifierAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#performIdentifierAction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation drawer: How do I set the selected item at startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In `onCreate()`, following code will load the first item's fragment upon first start:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.posts, 0);
}
```

Thanks to [calvinfly for this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043219/how-to-select-the-first-item-in-a-navigation-drawer-and-open-a-fragment-on-appli#comment50111515_31043219).

Comment: Where did you put this code to make sure it only runs on start, and not every time the activity is created?

Comment: Also, this selects the first item but doesn't mark it as checked inside the menu. :/

Comment: I have put it in `onCreate`, for item checking `if (menuItem.isChecked())
                            menuItem.setChecked(false);
                        else
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);` worked for me.

BTW I am no longer using this instead I am now using [THIS](https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign) library

Answer (score 17):

Add `android:checked="true"` to your first menu item.

And manually select one item, using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, postListFragment).commit();
```

to open fragment.

Comment: its already added but when activity starts it shows blank page i.e. activities content view I want to replace that with fragment, I know I can directly do this with FragmentTransaction but I want to select first navigation item in drawer programatically!

Comment: Add  `android:checked="true"` just make menu have selected state. And see my revised answer to open fragment.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of normal listener ...

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelected(new Navigation.View.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {bla, bla, bla})
```

Create the listener as an Obj:

```
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navViewListener;
            navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(navViewListener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {bla, bla, bla})
```

...and use the Obj to trigger the listener event:

```
navViewListener.onNavigationItemSelected(navView.getMenu().getItem(0));
```

...where getItem(0) is the first menu item.

Use a method getItem(0).setChecked(true) or android:checked="true" at its menu item XML definition.

Comment: perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.default)`([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setCheckedItem(int))) after you setup your navigationview.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in `onCreate` method:

```
FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftrans.replace(R.id.container, <yourfragment>).commit();
```

Work for me !

Answer (score 0):

This can be done even better while considering orientation and other configuration changes. We could select whatever nav drawer menuitem depending on whether we are coming from a previous state. Check: For the Navigation drawer wielding Activity:-

```
public static final String SELECTED_NAV_MENU_KEY = "selected_nav_menu_key";
// The selected grid position
private int mSelectedNavMenuIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

   ...........................................................

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Recover assets
        mSelectedNavMenuIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_NAV_MENU_KEY);

        // Recover menu as selected
        MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
        toggleNavMenuItemCheck(menuItem);
        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(menuItem.getItemId(), mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
        return;
    } else {
        MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
        toggleNavMenuItemCheck(menuItem);
        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(menuItem.getItemId(), mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
    }
}
```

The toggle method that helps uncheck or check the menu item

```
private void toggleNavMenuItemCheck(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.isChecked()){
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
    }  else {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

This is how I save the state of the selected menu item. Check:-

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_explore:
                showExploreFragment(null);
                mSelectedNavMenuIndex = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_orders:
                mSelectedNavMenuIndex = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                mSelectedNavMenuIndex = 2;
                break;
            default:
                showExploreFragment(null);
                mSelectedNavMenuIndex = 0;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

// Save any important data for recovery
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_NAV_MENU_KEY, mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
    }
```

**NB: The line with code:**

```
navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(menuItem.getItemId(), mSelectedNavMenuIndex);
```

Can be replaced by the code:

```
onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

in `menu.xml` remember to mention `android:checkable="true"` for single item and `android:checkableBehavior="single"` for a group of items.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/pos_item_help"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Help" />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_nav_home" />
    </group>
```

then inside `NavigationItemSelectedListener` use `setCheckedItem(R.id.item_id_in_menu)` to make it selected.

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.pos_item_pos:
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.pos_item_pos);
                break;
            case R.id.pos_item_orders:
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.pos_item_orders);
                break;
            default:
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And you do not have to do the dirty task of managing the selected item anymore. navigationView manages it by self.

Answer (score 0):

1.) To land to the HomeFragment initially, use this inside your onCreate() in MainActivity:

```
Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
// replacing the fragment
if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

2.) To set the item as selected in navigationDrawer set the item as checked in navigation_menu.xml

```
 android:checked = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better to set the

```
app:startDestination="@+id/nav_item"
```

To choose first NavigationView.