# Navigation Drawer Item ByDefault selected not on click andorid

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am new to android, I am using navigation drawer for displaying my item list.

I faced some issues, Like when i come to my navigation Activity, the list name as Restaurant displayed. This Restaurant item as well included in my drawer item which is similar to other one. First time when I come to Navigation Activity, I want to highlight restaurant item. How Can I do it?

Kindly tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple one line code:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

and You can select(highlight) the item by calling

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
```

and where to call and item index solution you can refer this link.. this will solve your all problem.

[Navigation drawer: How do I set the selected item at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup)

if its not then copy your code so i can tell you how to use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use function:

```
ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked);
```

or

```
ListView.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
    public void run() {
       ListView.setSelection(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you at least read the question properly, because you are confusing newbie developers.. i know your approach is also right in some cases.. but dont do this.