# Opening fragment from other fragment : Drawer

Tags: android

I am using the below code to open another fragment from one fragment:

```
track nextFrag= new track();
login.this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, nextFrag, null)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Code works fine ( I can se ethe new fragment loaded) but the drawer keeps on highlighting the old one (as currently selected). How can I open a fragment and at the same time show it as currently selected in the drawer.

Comment: If you use Android Support Library v23 or above, you can use [NavigationView.setCheckedItem(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setCheckedItem(int)). For more informations, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31233478/3572108)

Comment: Thanks, post it as answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: No problem. I did it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section: If you use Android Support Library v23 or above, you can use [NavigationView.setCheckedItem(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setCheckedItem(int)). For more informations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup/31233478#31233478).