# Setting current item of WearNavigationDrawer programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, wear-os

Is it possible to set the current item of a `WearNavigationDrawer` programmatically?  I have two items that the user can swipe through to change the type of data displayed in the main view.  I want the selection to persist after the app is closed (i.e. save the current selection with `SharedPreference` and select that item in `onCreate`).

I can see from the compiled code that `WearableNavigationDrawer` wraps around a private `ViewPager`.  If I could access that, I could call `setCurrentItem(int position)`.  Is there anything short of creating a custom view?  Switching pages programmatically seems like something `WearNavigationDrawer` should be able to do.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup