# How to setup a listview first element pressed in a navigationview?

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, pressed

I have checked the [Navigation drawer: How do I set the selected item at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup) post. In that post the navigation drawer has a menuview, and my navigation drawer has a listview.

I have a navigation drawer, and a list init. I have setup my list whenever an item chosen, the item gets in a pressed state and highlights the chosen list item. This function works well and looks as following.

```
activityBinding.list.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
                parent.getChildAt(position).setPressed(true);
});
```

I have an xml, which is set on the listviev textcolor attribute. The xml looks like that:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#ffffffff"/> 
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="#ff0000ff"/> 
<item android:color="#00000000"/>
```

However I would like to setup the first item of the list pressed as default, before opening the drawer. My question is: How to get to an item of a list an set it to pressed outside of the setOnItemListener?

Comment: If would help if you can post the XML layout and Java code that you have worked till now. Otherwise this is very vague.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation drawer: How do I set the selected item at startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup)

Comment: @Divers I have seen that post, I have a list in my navigation drawer and not a menu.

Answer (score 0):

`activityBinding.list.getChildAt(0).setPressed(true)`

But you should use `NavigationView` and not `ListView`.

Comment: I have tried that and I get a nullpointer exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setPressed(boolean)' on a null object reference. I also followed: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, which has a listview in the navigationdrawer.

Comment: Then please fix it as explained there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it . That problem is not related to your question.

Comment: I found the solution which detailed above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for my problem.

```
activityBinding.list.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                activityBinding.list.getChildAt(0).setPressed(true);
                activityBinding.list.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```