# navigation drawer item not checked by default

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Here's my xml for the navigation drawer items

```
<item android:title="Movies"
    android:checkable="true">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/movies" 
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item // this needs to be checked by default
                android:id="@+id/upComingMovies"
                android:title="Up Coming"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_movies"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/inCinemaMovies"
                android:title="In Cinemas"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_movies"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/popularMovies"
                android:title="Popular Now"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_movies"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/topRatedMovies"
                android:title="Top Rated"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_movies"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

My activity code

```
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

But this doesn't keep the item checked by default, but when i click on any item it gets checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, you are setting property `setChecked(true)` after `findviewbyId`.
First set you navigation menu then set the property.
And use `navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);` which is introduce in API 23.

[Check this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup)

Answer (score 1):

Set in you xml android:checked="true" for item what you want set as default.

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/upComingMovies"
    android:title="Up Coming"
    android:checked="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_movies"/>
```