# Select default navigation drawer item

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

When my app first loads I would like the first option in the navigation drawer to be selected by default. Currently, nothing is selected.

Previous similar questions have suggested using `getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true)` or `setCheckedItem()` but I am unsure where these would be used.

Main Activity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

        val topLevelDestinations: HashSet<Int> = HashSet(listOf(R.id.toDoList, R.id.allTasks, R.id.settings))

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view).setupWithNavController(navController)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build()
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you need to set checked item  in onCreate() after initiate navigation drawer.

Comment: What should checked item be set on?

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233279/navigation-drawer-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-at-startup)

Comment: I have looked at that but I am unsure what the `navigationView` is

Comment: navigationView is your "nav_view"  in your layout.